# Is an MSAccess database with .NET portable?

Tags: .net, ms-access

In my A-Level project I have all the record info stored in an MS Access database file. I'm just wondering, can I bundle this file with the software and not require the computer the software is running on to have MS Access installed?

The reason I ask is that if finished, this program will be ran on my college network to handle room bookings and they don't have MS Access installed.

Thanks.

Comment: SLaks: G.C.E. A Level I presume, the one before entering University or colleges: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GCE_Advanced_Level

Comment: You should accept answers for your questions by clicking the hollow check mark next to your favorite answer for each question.

Comment: A-Levels are what SLaks said, they're qualifications that get you into University. I'm taking a Computing A-Level and out final project has to be researched and coded ourselves.

Thanks for the replies, I know what i need now. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you're using OleDb, your users do not need Access.

However, unless they have Access or a compatible program, they will not be able to look at the data on their own (without your program).

Comment: In this kind of scenario isn't it desirable that they can't look at the data so they can't alter it in a way that the logic of the app is designed to prevent eg. entering multiple bookings for the same room at the same time

Comment: @RobV: That may or may not be true, depending on the context.  I'm not saying that it's a drawback; I'm just pointing it out.

Comment: What RobV said was right, they shouldn't be able to edit anything unless through the app, which will have significant protection in place to prevent abuse.

Thanks for the answers anyway, puts my mind at rest.

Answer (score 2):

Correct, you don't need Access. We have several ASP web apps on our server that does not have Microsoft Access.

Answer (score 0):

the Jet engine is needed to work with MS Access files.

> Jet has been part of Windows itself
>   since Win2000
>    -- David W. Fenton

Microsoft has details on [How to obtain the latest service pack for the Microsoft Jet 4.0 Database Engine](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239114)

Comment: While Jet 4.0 is part of Windows, that doesn't necessarily mean you have OLEDB and/or DAO installed and registered correctly. I *think* many people have said that DAO is there on a clean install of Windows, but I'm not at all sure of that. I don't have any computers without multiple versions of Access installed on them, so can't check.